# Iframe not visible in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-9

I'm working with a jquery music player inside an Iframe.
I tested the page on Chrome and Firefox and the iframe shows correctly, but in IE it appears invisible and the music wont start.

**HTML:**

```
        <iframe id="player" src="include/iwishplayer/index.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**CSS:**

```
#player {width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; left:700px; bottom:-50px}
```

**URL:**

http://gabrielmeono.com/working/

Answer (score 0):

Try other players, seems that the player you have is not working correctly

http://superdit.com/2011/04/27/12-jquery-plugins-for-playing-audio-video-files/

remember that audio tag will not work on IE below version 9, in this case some players use Flash instead

you can 'fix' your existing plugin and modify the code

`$(this).append('<source src="' + audioSource + '.' + fileExt + '">');`

to
`$(this).attr("src", audioSource + "." + fileExt);`

Some samples for audio for IE you can find
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589489(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try disabling activeX filtering in IE settings

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to the latest jQuery version on the iframe source. I experienced similar issues on IE9, and this solved my problem (I upgraded from v1.9.1 to v1.10.2).

In my case IE raised this exception: *`SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.`*

Useful info can be found here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13378